# randomly add NA values across columns in data

Tags: r

I have something like this:

```
dates <- seq(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2017-12-01"), "1 day")

values = cumsum(rnorm(length(dates)))

df <- cbind(dates, values)
```

Which looks like:

```
  dates     values
1 14610 -0.3750827
2 14611  0.2068051
3 14612  0.1986609
4 14613  0.1793758
5 14614  1.1068358
6 14615  0.9621490
```

I would like to add randomly to the data NA values such that:

```
  dates     values
1 14610 -0.3750827
2 NA     NA
3 14612  0.1986609
4 14613  0.1793758
5 NA     NA
6 14615  0.9621490
```

Where some rows have NA values in. I have found code to randomly add NA values but only to one column.

```
ind <- sample(df, 100)
df[ind] <- NA
```

Does not work for me.

Comment: `df[sample(nrow(df), 100), ] <- NA`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas That'd only turn random rows to `NA` although on second look at the post it may indeed be what OP is looking for even though the description doesn't explicitly say so.

Comment: @Shree Yes, that is the point, I guess. To turn random *matrix* entries to `NA` it could be `is.na(df) <- sample(length(df), 100)`, treating `df` as a vector (with a `dim` attribute). In the post `df` has a misleading name, it is not a data.frame. Or maybe the OP is committing the frequent mistake of not using `data.frame(dates, values)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it your way, you'd need an array of same dimensions as `df` with random `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s so that you can replace the `TRUE`s with `NA`. Here's a way -

```
ind <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), prod(dim(df)), replace = T),
              nrow = nrow(df), ncol = ncol(df))

df[ind] <- NA
```